# how to convert list of strings to list of lists

Tags: python-3.5

In Python how do I convert:

```
list a = [ 'i am going to America', 'i will come by tomorrow evening' ]

    into

list b = [ [i am going to America], [i will come by tomorrow evening] ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension.

```
>>> a = [ 'i am going to America', 'i will come by tomorrow evening' ]
>>> [[x] for x in a]
[['i am going to America'], ['i will come by tomorrow evening']]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **List Comprehensions** and generate another list

```
list_a = [ 'i am going to America', 'i will come by tomorrow evening' ]
print(list_a) # ['i am going to America', 'i will come by tomorrow evening']

list_b = [[x] for x in list_a]
print(list_b) # [['i am going to America'], ['i will come by tomorrow evening']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare each entry as list and then append it to the main_list

```
list = ['i am going']
main_list.append(list)
```

try this:

```
list = ['iam g', 'here']
 main_list = []
main_list.append(list)
 print main_list
output: [['iam g', 'here']]
 main_list.append(list)
 print main_list
output: [['iam g', 'here'], ['iam g', 'here']]
```